# How to loop through a list to a class

Tags: python, for-loop

I have been trying to figure out how to use lists using one variable.

The code I am using right now:

```
catalog = ['Hello', 'World']

itemLists = item.getFeed(catalog) #It is not important what item.getFeed does
# However an exception will pop out due to there is a list of catalog.
```

My issue here is that I want to add one by one that are in the lists to:

`itemLists = item.getFeed(catalog)`

For example it would end up like this:

```
itemLists = item.getFeed(Hello)
itemLists = item.getFeed(World)
```

however this would override the itemLists and what I am trying to do is that I want to each value in the list to be append into the itemLists.

How could I make a simple line that would use all items that are in the `catalog` to run:

```
itemLists = item.getFeed(x)
```

one by one?

Comment: Please add a minimal example as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think (if I understand your question correctly) that you want to `append` to the list?

This should work:

```
itemLists = list()
for element in catalog:
    itemLists.append(item.getFeed(element))
```

Or it can be done with a *list comprehension* like this:

```
itemLists = [item.getFeed(x) for x in catalog]
```

Learn more about list comprehensions at the official Python Tutorials: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Or `itemLists = list(map( item.getFeed, catalog ))` if we're trying to give them some options.

Comment: There it is! The one with`itemLists = [item.getFeed(x) for x in catalog]` was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a "for" loop. For every item in your iterable, do something.

```
catalog = ['Hello', 'World']
for x in catalog:
    itemLists = item.getFeed(x)
    # do something with itemLists here because it'll be
    # overwritten on the next iteration.
```

Comment: The question has some grammar errors, so maybe I read it wrong, but to me it sounds like the over writing is the entire problem that they're trying to solve. Your answer still overwrites the list. Maybe you could tell them about `itemList.append`

Comment: @mypetlion It looks like I misunderstood the question. I'm upvoting Unapiedra. Thanks!